# Django Base url Redirection for API

Tags: python, django, swagger

[image]i am new to Django Python and working on redirection of Apis I am Having issues in Redirection.
For ex : www.example.com  which is working now and the second server is www.api.example.com in which i have to redirect all the apis from www.example.com to www.api.example.com and  /apis are all the apis which is  will remain the same for api hits.

```
url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(permanent = False, url='https://api.example.com/'), name='static_data'),
```

It redirects to the url but the parameters (fields which are created in swagger to hit) does not pass.
As i have registered all the api in the default router  like

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'v1/api1', api1VisitViewSet, "api1")

Comment: What parameters?

Comment: fields which are there in the api which needs to hit ..

Comment: Can you give an example of the URL with parameters?

Comment: please check the photo added for ex : this is running on the www.example.com and i need these api to run on api.example.com and remaining subpaths will be the same and the viewsets too.

Comment: i tried this
    url(r'^/api/v1/(?P<path>.*)/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='https://example.com/api/v1/%(path)s/', permanent=True), name='/api/v1/'),

it works till v1 but when trying for sub paths like v1/login then it doesnt redirects